# How to set metadata in S3 using boto?

Tags: python, amazon-s3, boto

I am trying to set metadata during pushing a file to S3.

This is how it looks like :

```
def pushFileToBucket(fileName, bucket, key_name, metadata):
    full_key_name = os.path.join(fileName, key_name)
    k = bucket.new_key(full_key_name)
    k.set_metadata('my_key', 'value')
    k.set_contents_from_filename(fileName)
```

For some reason this throws error at set_metadata saying :

```
boto.exception.S3ResponseError: S3ResponseError: 403 Forbidden
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><Error><Code>SignatureDoesNotMatch</Code></Error>
```

And when I remove this `set_metadata` part, the file is getting stored correctly.
Not sure what I am doing wrong. If the access key was invalid, then it wouldn't have saved the file anyway!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Got this fixed. Apparently we cannot have an `underscore` in the metadata key name.

Comment: Also, metadata keys are converted to lower case, and if you use conflicting keys that only differ by their capitalisation (for example `'MyKey'` and `'mykey'`), then you will get the same type of error.

Answer (score 4):

Another approach for someone using upload_file:

```
s3 = boto3.client('s3')
path = 'foo/bar.json'
file = 'bar.json'
bucket_name = 'foobar_bucket'
extra_args = {'CacheControl': 'max-age=86400'}
s3.upload_file(path, bucket_name, file_name, extra_args)
```

This would set the Cache-Control header on the file.

Comment: Wonderful! It's hard to find good examples for `upload_file[obj]` using `extra_args`

Comment: This doesnt seem to work. When I tried this, extra_args only let's you set aws predefined attributes, no custom attributes, which is what this question seemed to be about.