# Is there a way to update metadata headers on Amazon S3 with boto3?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I am trying to check all the keys in an S3 bucket, if it has a certain userd-defined metadata header, then move onto the next, but it does not have the user-defined metadata header -- I want to add it with a certain key value pair. I have been trying to do some kind of `put` command but I am fairly new to this.

I have gotten this far:

Basically able to print all the keys within my specified bucket

```
import boto3

s3 = boto3.resource('s3')


# This will search ALL of the files within a specified bucket
my_bucket = s3.Bucket('client-data')

for file in my_bucket.objects.all():
    print(file.key)
```

If I am able to do a conditional statement saying if the metadata header does not exist, then add it, that would be awesome. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: you only get the metadata when you download iirc

Comment: Combine https://stackoverflow.com/a/18981298/2372812 with https://stackoverflow.com/a/53694378/2372812 ?